# fetchメソッドのエラー処理で"Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."が表示させないようにする方法を教えてください

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, 非同期, promise

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

GitHubに公開している[fetch_catch.html](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch10/blob/master/fetch_catch.html)を実行すると、コンソール画面に下記のエラーが表示されます。エラーが表示されないようにするためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.    fetch_catch.html:1
```

#### 【質問の補足】

1.

fetch_catch.htmlは、[scripts/fetch_catch.js](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch10/blob/master/scripts/fetch_catch.js)を読み取って「指定したファイルが存在しません。」と表示させる意図で作成しました。

2.

fetch_catch.jsの2行目で`fetch('nothing.php')`としていますがnothing.phpは作成していません。Promiseオブジェクトのfetchメソッドに置いて通信エラーが発生したときの動作を確認するためです。

3.

英語版のstackoverflowを確認すると、[Promise error The message port closed before a reponse was received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154963/promise-error-the-message-port-closed-before-a-reponse-was-received)と言う質問があります。これを読んでいると「Google Chromeの設定を変更すれば良い」と言うことが書かれていると思います。ただChromeのどこをどう変えれば良いのか分かりません。

4.

ブラウザはGoogle Chromeでローカル開発環境は[Wocker](https://qiita.com/mikakane/items/1bbabe4d27bebf28fd00)を使用しています。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: リンク先の英語版stack overflowで言っていることは、「Chromeに入っている拡張機能を無効化してみると良い」ということだと思います。エラーメッセージ中にある `runtime.lastError`というのは拡張機能に関連する機能であり、`fetch_catch.html`や`scripts/fetch_catch.js`に問題があるのではなく何らかの拡張機能が問題を発生させている可能性が高いと思われます。

Comment: Faily Feely さん。早速のコメントありがとうございます。Chromeの拡張機能を調べた結果、 **Norton Safe Web** をOFFにすると、質問で述べたエラーが表示されなくなりました。アドバイス助かります。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。